# Getting error when trying to update Product Prices index in Magento

Tags: indexing, special-price

I'm getting the following error after attempting to index Product Prices in Magento: **Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice**

Screenshot here: http://grab.by/DRzK

Any advise what the issue is and how to resolve?

Comment: Additionally, I came across this support forum disscussion on Magento [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/index.gif/viewthread/1057440/#t484573), but I'd rather not modify db unless I absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

You have a product with an invalid special pricing startdate, most likely from a bad import, updating using the api without error checking your values, or some query that put the value in the db without any error checking or requiring it to re-index after saving the product.

When I ran into this, I was heavily using the api, so I used the api to create a report of all products and their promotion start and end dates.  I was able to identify the ones in the wrong format, and after correcting those values I could re-index again.  You could also look in the db if you aren't using the api.  For me, finding and correcting the bad values was all it took to get it to run again without error.  Just be sure to build more error checking into however you load this data or it will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the backend model is failed to load. The error appears to be with the model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Startdate_Specialprice`.

Validate that this file exists as I think it should be, at least in my version 1.9 it is there, if it is not there than simply download it and add it to you Magento install. It might also be worth checking if other files are missing.